# Is it possible to create a honeytoken as an image file?

Tags: honeypot

I though it would be an interesting idea for my final year project.

*A honeypot token in an image form, with a hidden script that will send you information about the user when the file is executed (opened with an image viewer). Main goal is to identify leaks and stolen data.*

But the more I research the topic, the more I understand why I couldn't find this option on canarytokens website. For example, when you create a word document (token) and open it with Word - it will open an empty document and send me an email alert with notes about what file was opened and from where. (This doesn't work if I open it with Notepad for example and will dispaly encrypted gibrish)

So from what I undersrood so far I'd have to focus on one specific image viewer program and design the token around it. Is that correct? Does the viewer has to be compromised or have a vulnerability?

First I thought to make a tracking pixel, but that's not a standalone image file.
Then thought to use steganography to encrypt a pixel in an image with the honeypot code, but then you need to decrypt it...

Am I chasing rainbows or is there a way I could approach this problem? Please be kind, I'm a noob.

Comment: Welcome to security.SE! This is a fun question and I hope someone posts a good answer. Maybe someone who reads it will know exactly how to answer it, but for me I know what all the buzzwords mean but I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You want to embed a script in an image file, and you want the script to run and phone home from the user's computer when they ... download it? ... open it in a particular image viewer? You say _"the more I understand why I couldn't find this option"_; can you explain what those reasons are? More info makes your question easier to answer.

Comment: It sounds like you want an image to do something when it is viewed; I think unless you have a specific image viewer in mind that has a vulnerability, you're not going to be able to get a regular image to execute any code.

Comment: fwiw, there *is* a corollary in the (mostly) audible parts of the spectrum: ultrasonic audio-beacons, eg. whereby a tv will emit a code and your phone will relay the fact that you 'observed something' or were 'nearby', viz. https://hackaday.com/2017/05/04/ultrasonic-tracking-beacons/ (also https://lisnr.com/technology/ and https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-35639549)

Comment: and there is also another similar concept in the banknote counterfeit prevention world, in the form of specific pattern(s) that scanning and multimedia software will detect (one such called *Omron rings* aka *the EURion constellation*, viz. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation) - whether the detection of these results in a beacon being sent to an/ interested party/ies is unknown, and likely to be software-specific

Comment: I've edited the question to add more context and addressed some of the questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you strip out all the extra layers about why you are pursuing this, you are left with a single function: the opening of an image to result in an automated action being performed.

That's not feasible.

It will be highly dependent on the viewer being used and the functions, or vulnerabilities, in that viewer. Just as Word files can have macros that can only be interpreted by Word and not notepad, you have the same problem with images. And there are a hundred different ways of viewing images.

A tracking pixel works because it's not about the image, but about the active link. If you can make the image a link to a resource you can control, then you can track where/when it is opened.